# Google Cloud storage "Security credentials are not valid" Using boto.gs.connection

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, boto

```
from boto.gs.connection import GSConnection
GSConnection?
GSConnection(self, gs_access_key_id=None, gs_secret_access_key=None, is_secure=True, port=None, proxy=None, proxy_port=None, proxy_user=None, proxy_pass=None, host='storage.googleapis.com', debug=0, https_connection_factory=None, calling_format=<boto.s3.connection.SubdomainCallingFormat object at 0x9dafd6c>, path='/', suppress_consec_slashes=True)

headers = {'x-goog-project-id': 'Given on Google Console'}

conn = GSConnection(gs_access_key_id=client_id, gs_secret_access_key=private_key_id)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden
                 The provided security credentials are not valid.
```

`account_type: "service_account"`

Where `client_id, private_key_id` are the credentials provided by `GCS` from file  `"project_name-id.json"`

while connecting `boto.storage_uri` works with same credential.

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
CLIENT_ID = client_id
CLIENT_SECRET =  private_key_id
gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
output = 'mybucket/test'
f = file('/home/user/test')
dst_uri = boto.storage_uri(output, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
dst_uri.new_key().set_contents_from_file(f)
```

What am i doing wrong?